# Why am i encountering an operand error in the following code?

Tags: python

Encountering an arror at this line -

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and self.fired == False and (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.last_shot) >= shot_cooldown:
```

Full Code-

```
class Weapon ():
    def __init__(self, image, arrow_image):
        self.original_image = image
        self.angle = 0
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle)
        self.arrow_image = arrow_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.fired = False
        self.last_shot = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    def update(self, player):
        shot_cooldown = 250
        arrow = None
        self.rect.center = player.rect.center

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x_dist = pos[0] - self.rect.centerx
        y_dist = -(pos[1] - self.rect.centery)
        self.angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y_dist, x_dist))

        #mouse clicks
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and self.fired == False and (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.last_shot) >= shot_cooldown:
                arrow = Arrow(self.arrow_image, self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery, self.angle)
                self.fired = True 
                self.last_shot = pygame.time.get_ticks
        #reset clicks
```

Expected the arrow in game to shoot, but on mouse-click the game crashed

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: General advice: Don't write `something == False`, write `not something`

Answer (score 2):

When you set:

```py
self.last_shot = pygame.time.get_ticks
```

`self.last_shot` is then a method rather than an integer and from that point forward any math you do ie `(pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.last_shot)` will result in a `TypeError`.

What you want to do of course is set it to the result of calling that function.

```py
self.last_shot = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k :)